# How can I Understand Time Dimension intuitively in Data Warehouse

Tags: sql, oracle12c, dimensional-modeling

I am new to dimensional modelling and it confuses the hell out of me. Hope someone can help me understand it. I will say an example. My shift table is below

```
shift_date |shift_status|request_id|Hrs_worked
-----------------------------------------
 09-01-2011|Filled      |8899      |5.5
21-01-2011 |Cancelled   |6677      |6
22-01-2011 |Filled      |7766      |2.5
```

and so on it goes..
This is essentially the table from where the fact table will read.

I want to create a Time dimension table. I am using sql developer.So my question is, should I only include the dates contained in the shift_date column? or should i develop a script to include each day of 2011? I will be doing analysis to see how many shifts were cancelled each month, how many filled each quarter etc. If anyone can help me understand the time dimension intuitively that will be great.

Answer (score 4):

First, instead of "Time", consider calling this dimension "Date", or "Calendar". 
"Time" dimension is usually designed to represent time (hours, minutes, etc). "Date" dimension is usually used to analyze events on a daily level. You can, of course, use both in a model.

The way to think about Date dimension: it exists regardless of your fact table, and represents calendar - either standard or fiscal or both. As any calendar, it must list every day, without any gaps. A subltle note: there exist many types of calendars, but usually and most commonly we use "solar    Gregorian" calendar. Occasionally, this assumption is not true and you will need to model a different type of calendar:
[Calendar Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_calendars)

Finally, you might need to choose dates range for your calendar dimension. People have different opinions on that. My approach is to start calendar table on date of earliest record in fact tables, and end on the date of the latest fact record. 
Alternative approach is to start from the first day of the year where first transaction occured, and end on the last day of the year of the last transaction. For example, if you fact table contains records from 2017-02-15 to 2018-04-10, you date table can span either exactly that range, or from 2017-01-01 to 2018-12-31.

Comment: Ok so the way I understood it from your explanation is that the  date dimension exists and is independent of all other tables(until we link them through keys), it will contain all the dates of the shift table(taking my example in question)  and not just those dates but all the dates in an year. Am i right?

Comment: @dwalker - yes, you are correct. Take a look at its actual use in the BI systems: https://www.excelcampus.com/tables/calendar-table-explained/

Answer (score 0):

You should go with each day of 2011 and you ca store multiple attributes like weekday, what fiscal quarter is it in.You can calculate at run time, but in a lot of cases it's better to pre-calculate. Few reasons i can think of having all dates in date dimension

1. Easy to find missing shifts.
2. If you have other attribute on date it can help you to determine when its missing may be some kind of analysis.
3. You don't have to add extra check if new date came then insert in dim first.